# Ring around wire on diagram

Tags: schematics, wiring

If this is a repeated question, please let me know.  I'm a hobbyist electronics person, and ran across symbols on a diagram I didn't recognize.  I've attached the image below:

[image: Wiring diagram]

What I'm trying to figure out is what the different rings around the wires mean.  For example, Earphone Pilot has a connection that shows a ring around one of the wires, and then that hits a T connection where all of them have rings around the wires, too.  I've been trying to look it up, but I'm having a really hard time finding info.  The full diagram is part of the wiring diagram for a Becker Avionics AR620X transceiver, and the diagram is on page 77 of the PDF [here](http://www.becker-avionics.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/AR620X_IO.pdf).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's shielded wire.

Comment: Gotcha, so it doesn't have anything to do with actual wiring, just type of wire?  I'm just trying to understand what I do with one wire connecting to the ring that circles another wire

Comment: That wire is connected to the shield around the other wire, then.

Comment: @isdi: That's an answer, not a comment!  Post it with pride.

Comment: Done! Didn't realize I hit the comment button, links don't work in those btw, hence the silly look at the end.

Comment: I am absolutely certain this question has been asked and answered before, but I can't find it...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's shielded wire. The ring around it is the outer shield around the cable linking the two parts together. The shield also provides the low side of the signal, so it needs to be connected to the ICs as well; it's the other half of the complete circuit. That T connection you mention is just showing that the shields for all the wires are connected together.

Comment: No problem. This does seem like something that would be hard to search for without knowing the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Felthry is correct. Normally this would be either small gauge coax cable or shielded hookup wire. Note that the shields are connected to various terminals, jacks, etc. The shield is not just 'floating' and surrounding the central wire. The note regarding isolation is to prevent noise from getting into the system from the airframe. An example is:

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Alpha-Wire/1703-SL005?qs=%252bd%252bj5ZauFZ%252bci10Syv%252bbmA%3D%3D